# Adding migrations: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found ILibraryManager

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Full error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.ILibraryManager
>   Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.get_LibraryManager()'.
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.ValidateProject(String
>   targetProject)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2_7.b__15()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
>   args)    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Command that I try to run:

> dnx ef migrations add test1

Version of EF commands:

> Entity Framework Commands 7.0.0-rc1-16348

Version of dnx:

> Microsoft .NET Execution environment Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc2-16595

My project currently use RC1. It all worked before.

Comment: You must update all parts of your solution to the same build level

Comment: @ErikEJ so, assuming that I want to work on RC1: what should I change to make it work? global.json is set to rc1-update1, all dependencies also work on rc1

Comment: is there some other place that I have to check if version is correct?

Comment: Looks like dnx is not rc1!

Comment: So how to change it? It thought that it can be done in global.json, but I have "1.0.0-rc1-update1" version there. All should be ok.

Comment: You don't. Your entity Framework is  `7.0.0-rc1-16348`, this is not rc1-final. And you need to install dnx rc1-final too (`dnvm upgrade latest` without the -u parameter, this will upgrade to latest unstable, i.e. rc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly sure the issue is the fact that you're mixing RC1 packages with RC2 runtime. Downgrade the runtime to RC1 or switch from `dnx` to `dotnet` and upgrade the packages to RC2